# cummlative count for each status with cascading handling for each status

Tags: mysql

I am using following query in mysql stored procedure which basically returns the all status and for each date in between start date and end date returns the count as well the cummulative count

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS date_range;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE date_range AS
SELECT DATE(p_StartDate) + INTERVAL (n-1) DAY AS date
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS n
  FROM detail 
  LIMIT 31 
) AS dates;


DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS date_status_combinations;
-- Cross join the date_range with production_statuses to get all possible combinations
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE date_status_combinations AS
SELECT ps.Id,ps.Status, dr.date
FROM date_range dr
CROSS JOIN productionstatus ps ;


SELECT
  dsc.Status,
  DATE(dsc.date) AS StatusDateTime,
  COALESCE(d.count, 0) AS count,
  SUM(COALESCE(d.count, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY dsc.Status ORDER BY DATE(dsc.date)) AS cumulative_count
FROM date_status_combinations dsc  
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    ProductionStatus,
    DATE(StatusDateTime) AS date,
    COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM detailunique
  WHERE DATE(StatusDateTime) BETWEEN DATE(p_StartDate) AND DATE(p_EndDate)
  GROUP BY ProductionStatus, DATE(StatusDateTime)
) d ON dsc.Status = d.ProductionStatus AND DATE(dsc.date) = DATE(d.date) 
WHERE  dsc.Id not in (0,1)
ORDER BY dsc.Status, DATE(dsc.date);
```

Now I want that for each status is should also handle the cacading of count , so suppose if some row have status 7 direct then it should be counted in 2,3,4,5,6 as well. (this is just an example )

Comment: Add all SQL sample code which allows to reproduce. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? What relationship in your database dictates that `status = 7` should be included in status `2,3,4,5,6`? Do not use constructs like ``WHERE DATE(StatusDateTime) BETWEEN DATE(p_StartDate) AND DATE(p_EndDate)``, as it requires a full table scan ([non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)). It should be rewritten as ``WHERE StatusDateTime >= p_StartDate AND StatusDateTime < p_EndDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY``.